# neural network: How Standard Scaler can affect to node weights learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I and learning about neural network, and i suspect about how effective of our feature scaling for deep model. In my opinion, Standard Scaler can lead to a bad results of neural network.

Let look at an example: I have a classification task for a data set with 2 features: A and B. After using Standard Scaler for both features, most of rows in dataset will become 0 ( Mean of Standard Scaler distribution is 0).So if we look at    neural network formula for one node of first hidden layer( which is after input layer):

`A.W1 + B.W2 + B1 = 0*W1 + 0*W2 + B1 = B1`

From above equation, if most of our rows are full of 0 values , we can see that when most of rows of our dataset doesn't change our weight of first hidden layer, and bias (`B1`) is the unique factor to pass over first hidden layer and will be updated after each iteration.

So as my conclusion, we shouldn't use Standard Scaler for input of neural network.

Does it correct ? And please correct me if i am wrong about my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

By applying Standard Scaler we do not loose any information. So, I believe that it cannot damage anything.

In your example, when A and B are almost always zeros, the weights W1 and W2 do not play any role. This is correct. However, if A and B are almost always 2.0 and 5.0, respectively, you will have the same situation (W1 and W2) will not play any role, everything will be decided via the bias.

The problem is not that A and B are (almost always) zeros. The problem is that they are (almost always) constants.

Comment: Let break down our problem is 2 phases:

Comment: 1. When our model sees an example with A=0, B=0 in first time, gradient descent do nothing > It can not start learning. But if our model sees an example with A = 2, B = 5, gradient descent will update our W1 and W2.

Comment: 2. After first time seeing the mode ( most frequented ) value of distribution, from second time, our gradient descent doesn't change so much becase it learnt in the past.

Comment: In my question, I want to to focus on the first time our model see ( phase 1 ), and your answer is corresponding for phase 2